# Insert the new node at the end of Linked list SEGV Error

Tags: c

Getting Segmentation error , please help issue in below c code logic.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

```html
/*
 * For your reference:
 *
 * SinglyLinkedListNode {
 *     int data;
 *     SinglyLinkedListNode* next;
 * };
 *
 */
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode *cur = head, 
    *new = malloc ( sizeof (struct SinglyLinkedListNode)), *prev;
    
    if ( head == NULL)
    {
        head = new;
        return head;
    }
    
    while ( cur != NULL)
    {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur -> next;
    }
    
    prev -> next = new;
    return head;
}
```

Error message

Comment: In the if block `if(head == NULL)` you must set head->next = NULL, otherwise it will point to some random location. Moreover, you are not using `data` anywhere inside your method.

Comment: Despite the points mentioned by the others, please consider two more things: 1. Check the return value of `malloc()`, if the allocation fails it returns `NULL`.  2. Don't declare your local variables in a comma separated. When you repeat the type for each variable and end the declaration with a semicolon on a single line the code gets much more readable.

Comment: Sure for the valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
cur = cur -> next; // You read an uninitialized value (garbage)
```

Set the values for the new node after reserving space

```
*new = malloc ( sizeof (struct SinglyLinkedListNode)) ...

new->data = data;
new->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks I have forgot to assign data, now its working.

Answer (score 0):

Modified to below code snippet, its working now, also removed extra prev pointer tracing.

```html
SinglyLinkedListNode* insertNodeAtTail(SinglyLinkedListNode* head, int data) {
    SinglyLinkedListNode *cur = head, 
    *new = malloc ( sizeof (struct SinglyLinkedListNode));
    // assigning the data in new node
    new -> data = data;
    new -> next = NULL;
    
    // check for NULL head
    if ( head == NULL)
    {
        head = new;
        return head;
    }
    
    // traverse till the end of the linked list
    while ( cur -> next != NULL)
        cur = cur -> next;
    
    // attach new node at the end of the linked list
    cur -> next = new;
    return head;
}
```